# How to represent a non-trivial kernel as a Gram matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, matrix, kernel-trick

Given a `kernel`, can we represent it as a `Gram matrix`? For example, a linear kernel can be presented (in Python/MATLAB code) in a Gram matrix as follows: `K = X*X.T`. If this is true, how to represent other non-trivial kernels in their Gram matrix form, e.g., check the following link, `page 5`, `equation 17` showing *Jensen-Shannon kernel*: `K(p,q) = exp(-JS(p||q))`

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3e43/4ca7cbd1869f41e338658f7ab4f954782ad8.pdf

How to write a Gram matrix representation of above kernel in Python?

Comment: It's unclear what you ask. Gram matrix of a kernel $K$ for vectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ is $n$ x $n$ matrix such that $K_{ij} = K(v_i, v_j)$.

Comment: What do you mean that $K = X$ and then $K = X X^T$?

Comment: I don't understand. How can $K(x1, x2) = X$ and $K(x1, x2) = XX^T$?

Comment: Ok, I have deleted that and modified my question. Now, I want to know how to write Gram matrix of kernel in my question above?

Comment: @Jakub Bartczuk Given a data matrix **X**, it's Gram matrix representation as a linear kernel would be **$XX^{T}$** which is square symmetric matrix.  I want to understand that for the given reference, how one could represent that kernel in its Gram matrix representation. The reason of confusion is that the authors are using distributions `p` & `q` in their kernel, and not the raw data matrix.